# Create Selection with ABAP

Tags: abap

I'm new in ABAP. I want my code to create a selection where I can enter a number and it shows me the list of my previously created customers.

this is the code:

```
REPORT ZBSP_CODING.

DATA: ls_ZBSPCUSTOMERS TYPE ZBSPCUSTOMERS,
  lt_ZBSPCUSTOMERS TYPE TABLE OF ZBSPCUSTOMERS,
  lv_KUNNR TYPE KUNNR.


SELECT-OPTIONS p_KUNNR FOR lv_KUNNR NO INTERVALS.


SELECT * FROM ZBSPCUSTOMERS INTO ls_ZBSPCUSTOMERS WHERE KUNNR IN p_KUNNR.
  WRITE: / ls_ZBSPCUSTOMERS-KUNNR,
         / ls_ZBSPCUSTOMERS-NAME_FIRST, ls_ZBSPCUSTOMERS-NAME_LAST,
         / ls_ZBSPCUSTOMERS-STREET, ls_ZBSPCUSTOMERS-HOUSE_NUM1,
         / ls_ZBSPCUSTOMERS-POST_CODE1, ls_ZBSPCUSTOMERS-CITY1.
ENDSELECT.
```

the problem is, it won't show me any customers. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is there any data in table ZBSPCUSTOMERS? Any data with the same selection you use in your program (p_kunnr)? You can check in transaction SE16 (or SE16N).

Comment: Yes I added the data before.

Comment: OK, than check if there is any conversion for field KUNNR in table ZBSPCUSTOMERS? What is the data element /domain behind this field? How the data is saved into the table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There will be two cases.-

1. Either `ZBSPCUSTOMERS` table doesn't contains any data.
2. or might be data mismatch for leading `0's` in data value for `KUNNR` field. So, Add these line-

> ```
> SELECT-OPTIONS p_KUNNR FOR lv_KUNNR NO INTERVALS.
>
>   "-------add below lines-----
>  LOOP AT p_KUNNR.
>       CALL FUNCTION 'CONVERSION_EXIT_ALPHA_INPUT'
>         EXPORTING
>           input  = p_KUNNR-low
>         IMPORTING
>           output = p_KUNNR-low.
>       MODIFY p_KUNNR.
>     ENDLOOP.
>   "-------End of addition-------------
>
>  SELECT * FROM ZBSPCUSTOMERS INTO ls_ZBSPCUSTOMERS WHERE KUNNR IN p_KUNNR.
>     WRITE: / ls_ZBSPCUSTOMERS-KUNNR,
>            / ls_ZBSPCUSTOMERS-NAME_FIRST, ls_ZBSPCUSTOMERS-NAME_LAST,
>            / ls_ZBSPCUSTOMERS-STREET, ls_ZBSPCUSTOMERS-HOUSE_NUM1,
>            / ls_ZBSPCUSTOMERS-POST_CODE1, ls_ZBSPCUSTOMERS-CITY1.
>   ENDSELECT.
> ```

CONVERSION_EXIT_ALPHA_INPUT Function module adds leading 0's in value. for ex- if DE size is 10 digit than if you enter 102, then it'll convert fron 102 to 0000000102.

Comment: p_kunnr was typed as kunnr (through lv_kunnr), so the conversion is carried out automatically by the system, calling the conversion FM is not necessary (and does not change anything).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but unfortunately it didn't work. 
Nothing happens when I press the Enter-Key. 
Maybe I'm completely wrong.

Comment: @JozsefSzikszai You're right. but in some system it fails. because for BU_PARTNER DE it fails in my system. so, i prefer checking it.

Comment: @Cesc nothing will happen on Enter-key. try executing (press F8).

Comment: LOL yes it was simply the F8 button...
Thank you all for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everybody it was as @divScorp mentioned it the **F8** button instead of the **Enter-Key**